# Check Enum values by label

Tags: c++, enums

Having something like this (example):

```
enum {
  label1,
  label2,
  //label3,
  label4,
  total}
```

Is it possible to check if any of the labels are present?

I need the `total` value in order to create matrices of the correct size, but need to know which of the labels are present in the list in order to perform operations specific to each item.

Comment: Not really possible in a sense you cant do Enum::label3 == undefined. Use list of strings or a smarted Enum class

Comment: It sounds like an enum might not be the best thing to use in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
enum My_Labels
{
    label1,  
    label2,  
    // label3,
    label4,  
    total
};

static My_Labels check1 = label1;
static My_Labels check2 = label2;
static My_Labels check3 = label3;
static My_Labels check4 = label4;
```

You should get a compilation error for any missing elements.

Also, if you comment out `label3`, the value of `label4` changes.